# Configure TMUX to display something different when control mode is entered

Tags: tmux

When you hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> you go into control mode, but sometimes the key stroke is not successful or I forget which mode I am in - is there a way to configure tmux so that it displays something different besides the green bar, so that you know what mode you are in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show if the prefix has been pressed with the `client_prefix` format, you can add something like this to `status-left` or whatever:

```
#{?client_prefix,PREFIX,}
```

Comment: does this belong in .tmux.conf? please be clear ty!

Comment: You need to add it to whereever you want in the status line, whether that be status-left, status-right or something else, for example: `set -g status-left "#{?client_prefix,PREFIX,}"`

Comment: so I have to run that manually everytime I run tmux? sorry I don't get it :(

I can drop into the ctrl menu at the bottom using  <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> so I run that `set -g` command from there, I guess just one time only since it's global?

Comment: also, how to unset it globally? that might be good to know.

Comment: would love to change the color instead of just some text in the bottom left, but this is pretty good thanks

Comment: It is not easy to change the colour of the entire status line when the prefix has been pressed at the moment, but you can change the colour of the text using an embedded style, something like `#{?client_prefix,#[bg=red]PREFIX#[default],}`.

Comment: that is awesome bro!!